# Java - Execution of AppleScript throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, macos, applescript

I'm creating a java program which controls iTunes. 
I created most of the code on my Mac mini. Everything works fine on the mini.
But when I try to run the program on my MacBook, I get an error.
The NullPointerException occurs when I try to run an AppleScript. But just on the MacBook.

Here is the code:

```
        String scriptRestart = "tell application \"iTunes\" \nset player position to 0 \nend tell";
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScriptEngine");
        try {
            engine.eval(scriptRestart); // NullPointerException
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Had someone a problem like this before? Is this error related to the java version?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I do know what an NullPointerException is. This is a strange problem, because it works on my mac mini, but not on my MacBook. So the code should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I do know what a null pointer exception is.

Comment: I think engine is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

It only works if you install "Java for OS X 2015-001".

After downloading here [LINK](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) , it works!

Comment: issue only on high sierra